# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, plugins, region, wavesurfer.js

So I'm trying to use the regions plugin from wavesurfer.js, but it keeps giving me this error in browser

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

This is how the code looks like:

```
const initializeWavesurfer = () => {
    return WaveSurfer.create({
        container: "#waveform",
        responsive: true,
        height: 80,
        waveColor: "indigo",
        progressColor: "purple"
})
}

const wavesurfer = initializeWavesurfer();

var RegionsPlugin = window.WaveSurfer.regions;

wavesurfer.addPlugin(RegionsPlugin.create({
    regionsMinLength: 2,
    regions: [
        {
            start: 1,
            end: 3,
            loop: false,
            color: 'hsla(400, 100%, 30%, 0.5)'
        }, {
            start: 5,
            end: 7,
            loop: false,
            color: 'hsla(200, 50%, 70%, 0.4)',
            minLength: 1,
            drag:true
        }
    ],
    dragSelection: {
        slop: 5
    }
})).initPlugin('regions');
```

The `wavesurfer.js` file is imported in the `HTML file` like this

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/wavesurfer.js@5.2.0/dist/wavesurfer.js"></script>
```

Also, I tried to import the `regions plugin`

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/wavesurfer.js/dist/plugin/wavesurfer.regions.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wavesurfer.js/5.2.0/plugin/wavesurfer.regions.js"></script>
```

Eveything else works, except the plugins. I tried other plugins too, but with the same result.
I think I've tried everything I could find on the internet to get this to work, but without any luck.
Please help and thank you in advance!

Comment: The error means that `WaveSurfer` is `undefined`.  Where do you import the `wavesurfer.js` file? That has to happen **before** your code runs.

Comment: @Pointy I edited the post to answer your question

Comment: OK, well where in the HTML do those `<script>` tags appear relative to your code?

Comment: At first the `<script>` tags were at the end of the `body`. I moved them in the `head` and now I don't get that error, but the plugin is still not working..